# flex-direction:row completely hides some items on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have div(class: review-tiems-container) with some items, on flex-direction:column they all show up, on flex-direction:row first one completely and some part of the second item disappear from screen, even when moving with mouse over mobile resolution.Even from editor mode hovering over their element, it shows empty space on dom.

this is how html looks, those item have inside content aswell but removed to reduce code length

```
  <div id="reviews">
        <h1 class="reviews-header">
            Hear what our customers 
            <span>
                are saying
                <img class="why-underline" src="./Imgs/why/headerunderline.png"/>
            </span>
        </h1>
        <section>
            <div class="review-info-bar">
                <div class="review-numbers">
                </div>
                <button class="review-btn">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="review-items-container">
                <div class="review-item">
                </div>
                <div class="review-item">
                </div>
                <div class="review-item">
                </div>
                <div class="review-item">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I tried different overflow options, none of them work

Comment: Please provide your css code as well so we can recreate your problem

Comment: try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your items-container if you would like them to wrap on mobile